# itext 7 Table runs off page

Tags: itext7

[image]I have a table that has  variable rows of data. In this example there are 56 rows.The table works fine and accuratly splits over two pages when it's the only thing on the document. When I add some information to the top of the page, company address and customer address at top (not really a header.)  It causes part of the table to push down and off the page (using setrelativeposition). The 56 rows will put rows 0-42 on the 1st page and then pick up with row 45 on the secod page.  Rows 43 and 44 are off the page as shown in the picture.

- Any Ideas or help would be appreciated. This is my 1st time with itext7

  Dim Dest As String = ("C:\Users\Dan\Documents\JM\SIG\37065.pdf")

  ```
   Dim Writer As PdfWriter = New PdfWriter(Dest)
   Dim Pdf As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(Writer)
   Dim document As New Document(Pdf)
   Dim Font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.COURIER)

   Dim Dateis As String = Now.ToShortDateString

   Dim dsItems As DataSet = JMGetData.GetDS("Select qty, item, cast(price as decimal(10,2)) as price, cast(salestax as decimal(10,2)) as salestax, cast(linetotal as decimal(10,2)) as linetotal from sales where invnbr = '" & invnbr & "'")

   Dim H1 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("J&M Home & Farm Supply")).SetFixedPosition(50, 800, 600).SetFontSize(9)
   Dim H2 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("1580 Elkton Pike")).SetFixedPosition(50, 790, 600).SetFontSize(9)
   Dim H3 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("Prospect TN 38477")).SetFixedPosition(50, 780, 600).SetFontSize(9)

   Dim cust1 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("Dan Tester")).SetFixedPosition(50, 750, 600).SetFontSize(9)
   Dim cust2 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("Street Addr")).SetFixedPosition(50, 740, 600).SetFontSize(9)
   Dim cust3 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("City State Zip")).SetFixedPosition(50, 730, 600).SetFontSize(9)

   document.Add(H1)
   document.Add(H2)
   document.Add(H3)
   document.Add(cust1)
   document.Add(cust2)
   document.Add(cust3)

   Dim pdftbl As New Table(6)

   pdftbl.AddCell("Qty").SetWidth(15%)
   pdftbl.AddCell("Item").SetWidth(40%)
   pdftbl.AddCell("Price").SetWidth(15%)
   pdftbl.AddCell("S-Tax").SetWidth(15%)
   pdftbl.AddCell("L-Total").SetWidth(15%)
   pdftbl.AddCell("Row").SetWidth(15%)

   For I As Int32 = 0 To dsItems.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

       Dim Qty As Int32 = CInt(dsItems.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("qty"))
       Dim Item As String = dsItems.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("item").ToString
       Dim Price As Decimal = CDec(dsItems.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("price").ToString)
       Dim stax As Decimal = CDec(dsItems.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("salestax").ToString)
       Dim Linetot As Decimal = CDec(dsItems.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("linetotal").ToString)

       pdftbl.AddCell(Qty).SetWidth(15%).SetFontSize(8)
       pdftbl.AddCell(Item).SetWidth(40%).SetFontSize(8)
       pdftbl.AddCell(Price).SetWidth(15%).SetFontSize(8)
       pdftbl.AddCell(stax).SetWidth(15%).SetFontSize(8)
       pdftbl.AddCell(Linetot).SetWidth(15%).SetFontSize(8)
       pdftbl.AddCell(I).SetWidth(15%).SetFontSize(8)

   Next
   pdftbl.SetWidth(500)
   pdftbl.SetRelativePosition(25, 90, 300, 700)
   document.Add(pdftbl)
   document.Close()

   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe", "C:\Users\dan\Documents\JM\Sig\37065.pdf")

   Me.Close()
  ```

Comment: (1) Just like using MS WORD, each page has a fixed layout size, and when the content of a Table exceeds the layout, it will naturally switch to another page.
(2) If you want to put them on the same page, you need to set the font size a little smaller, or adjust the bottom margin of the page a little smaller.
(3) But if there is a little more information next time, it may still cause your form to change pages. So please confirm that it is reasonable to require that the form must be on the same page?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `SetRelativePosition` after all? Most likely using that method simply is not the right way to do what you want.

Comment: I thought I had added an image of the issue. I just added it now.  

--life888888 it does carry over to the next page correctly but when I add the company and cust infor it pushes what was on page one off the bottom of the page then splits the table.  

mkl - with the relative position I was just trying to start the table below the customer information with some spaceing for cosmetic reason. I still have the same issue of the table running off the 1st page without it.  BTW I cut lines 7-35 off the image to make it fit better here.

Comment: What happens if you don't call `SetRelativePosition`?